# How to redirect html pages internally in Django?

Tags: django, django-oscar

I've included Product and services in Navbar links,
If I click on Product link it should redirect to services page.
I'm Using Django-Oscar. So I don't want to mess around with the urls.py and view.py.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mess with urls and views rather just use javascript. So just add something similar to this on the navlink/navitem.

```
onclick="window.location.href = '{% url 'yoururl' %}';"
```

Comment: I need to go to 'localhost:8000/catalogue' when I click on 'localhost:8000' only with the help of urls.py